# lib simples para salvar dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo alguns sites institucional simples, estáticos, e quero colocar algumas personalizações. Essas personalizações, serão poucas e simples, e serão acessadas apenas por um usuário. Mas terá uma ou outra informação que será alterada por mais de um usuário.

Sei que o sqlite é bom para esse tipo de coisa, mas não queria depender 
de outras libs. E não precisa ser um banco de dados para aplicar normalização.

Pensei em um simples arquivo texto com algum tipo de lock com arquivo, mas com certeza, alguém já implementou e fez com boas práticas.

Pretendo usar isso em uma hospedagem compartilhada que tem acesso a disco, e não quero configurar banco de dados, pois é algo muito simples, e quero fácil implantação.